# PHP SoapClient SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: element has both 'type' attribute and subtype

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client, webservice-client

I am using PHPs SoapClient for calling a SOAP web service. Below is how I am instantiating SoapClient instance.

`$client = new SoapClient('customer.wsdl',array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,"trace" => 1));`

The problem I am facing is whenever the above line executes, it throws an exception "**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: element has both 'type' attribute and subtype**". As a result the $client variable always holds NULL value i.e. not getting instantiated.

Below is the XSD schema which I think is causing the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:db="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/custom/soaprovider/plsql/xx_get_cust_pkg/get_customer/" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/custom/soaprovider/plsql/xx_get_cust_pkg/get_customer/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <element name="InputParameters">
      <complexType>
         <sequence>
            <element name="P_CUSTOMER_NAME" type="string" db:index="1" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
         </sequence>
      </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="OutputParameters">
      <complexType>
         <sequence>
            <element name="X_MSG_STATUS" type="string" db:index="2" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            <element name="X_MSG_DATA" type="string" db:index="3" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            <element name="X_CUST" type="db:APPS.XX_GET_CUST_PKG_X3326749X1X4" db:index="4" db:type="Array" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
         </sequence>
      </complexType>
   </element>
   <complexType name="APPS.XX_GET_CUST_PKG_X3326749X1X5">
      <sequence>
         <element name="CUSTOMER_NAME" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
         <element name="PARTY_NUMBER" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
         <element name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
         <element name="ACCOUNT_DESC" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
         <element name="BILL_TO_ADDRESS" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
         <element name="SHIP_TO_ADDRESS" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
         <element name="PRICE_LIST" db:type="VARCHAR2" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <simpleType>
               <restriction base="string">
                  <maxLength value="240" />
               </restriction>
            </simpleType>
         </element>
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="APPS.XX_GET_CUST_PKG_X3326749X1X4">
      <sequence>
         <element name="X_CUST_ITEM" type="db:APPS.XX_GET_CUST_PKG_X3326749X1X5" db:type="Struct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" />
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
</schema>
```

The PHP version I am running on currently is **5.4.30**

## **Edit(13th March 2015)**

There is a bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68576 logged on PHP bug tracker for the same issue, the status of which is still open. Please let know if there are any other workarounds to get through the issue apart from modifying the PHP source code.

Comment: Anyone found solution for this error as I am also facing same...